# unable to get jquery validation for captcha working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

i have been trying to validate the captcha in real time and i am using jquery validation version 1.11.1.
i have stored the value of the captcha in a session variable name security_code. i am using remote method of jquery. I am using it first time(jquery validation plugin and it is for learning purpose only).

this is my code showing what i have tried.

index.html

```
<label class="field">
<input type="text" name="securitycode" id="securitycode" class="gui-input sfcode" placeholder="Enter code">
</label>
```

validfile.js

```
securitycode:{
                required:true,
                remote: {
                url: "a.php",
                type: "post"
            },
messages:{
          securitycode:{
                required: 'Please enter security code',
                remote: 'Please enter correct security code'
                }
         }
```

a.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['securitycode']))
{
    if($_POST['securitycode']==$_SESSION['security_code'])
    {
        exit("true");
    }
    else exit("false");
}
exit();
?>
```

Note: I have included all the valid files and also am i the correct direcotry

thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've listed as `validfile.js`.... what is that?  Did you forget to show the rest of it?  Is that properly contained within the `.validate()` method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it, stupid me i always forget to add session_start(); in my php file. Sorry for wasting your time fellas.
 So the solution to this is add session_start(); in a.php

Comment: Another important part of the solution is to make sure your JavaScript doesn't have any critical syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` instead of `exit`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['securitycode']))
{
    if($_POST['securitycode']==$_SESSION['security_code'])
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else echo "false";
}
exit();
?>
```

**TIP**:

If everything is properly setup and `remote` is firing, you'll be able to see the server response from your browser console.  Otherwise, inspect your console for errors.

---

**EDIT**:

I assume this code is within the `.validate()` method, however, you appear to be missing some braces and things...

```
$('#yourForm').validate({ // <- you did not show us this part?
    rules: { // <- this was missing, maybe you just forgot it when posting the question
        securitycode: {
            required:true,
            remote: {
                url: "a.php",
                type: "post"
            }  // <- this was missing, closing brace for 'remote'
        }      // <- this was missing, closing brace for 'securitycode'
    },         // <- closing brace for 'rules'
    messages: {
        securitycode: {
           required: 'Please enter security code',
           remote: 'Please enter correct security code'
        }
    },
    // other options and callbacks
});
```

Comment: @user3135970, I don't know what else to tell you as this is pretty standard stuff.  Have you looked at your console?  It will always tell you the response from the server when `remote` is invoked.